# DBAL Connection query() function and SELECT FOR UPDATE, LOCK

Tags: mysql, doctrine, locking, dbal

I'm trying to do a 'SELECT FOR UPDATE' query in mysql using the DBAL connection query function.

I'm in a symfony project and I made the following test :

I have this two functions  in my controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("test", name="test")
 */
public function testAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM CommandeDel
            WHERE IDCommande = 2 FOR UPDATE";
        $m = $em->getConnection()->query($sql)->fetch();
        sleep(20);
        $em->getConnection()->commit();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        $em->getConnection()->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }

    return new Response(json_encode($m));
}

/**
 * @Route("test2", name="test2")
 */
public function test2Action()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
        $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM CommandeDel
            WHERE IDCommande = 2";
        $m = $em->getConnection()->query($sql)->fetch();
        $em->getConnection()->commit();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        $em->getConnection()->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }

    return new Response(json_encode($m));
}
```

I'm calling the first url (test) in my browser and immediatly the second one (test2) in an other  tab.

My problem is that the second one return immediatly the answer without waiting the 20 second delay...

Do someone see where I'm wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake, the SELECT FOR UPDATE query only lock the row for others SELECT FOR UPDATE queries and not for normal SELECT. I miss understood  the basic definition. To make the test works the second Action should look like this :

```
/**
 * @Route("test2", name="test2")
 */
public function test2Action()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM CommandeDel
            WHERE IDCommande = 2 FOR UPDATE";
        $m = $em->getConnection()->query($sql)->fetch();
        $em->getConnection()->commit();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        $em->getConnection()->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }

    return new Response(json_encode($m));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have it wait for 20 minutes, so add sleep(20):

```
$m = $em->getConnection()->query($sql)->fetch();
sleep(20);
$em->getConnection()->commit();
```

Comment: `sleep(20)` will wait 20 seconds, not minutes

Comment: Yes, I meant to say wait for 20 seconds, The code is okay though only my explanation. thanks.